# OpenCV Haar Cascades --- HEAD

Tags: opencv, cascade

I need to find a Head Cascade to identify a human head. Head to shoulders works ok, but I need a more precise one. There is too much "white space" from the hair to the top of the box. Anyone have any suggestions? Ive checked the following locations and didn't find much anything really....

http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34

as well as the opencv github